# Book - bash scripting and unix commands

Tags: bash, unix, command

I am beginning to learn Bash shell scripting in Unix environment and was looking for a good book/reference guide which would include the following:

- Bash scripting - basics (conditionals, loops etc.), as well as more advanced concepts
- unix command overview - explaining the basic commands such as grep,find etc. with a clear example of their usage to solve common problems in UNIX such as, removing all files older than 3 days, finding all files containing "foo" in them etc.

Do you guys know of any such manual/book?

Comment: This is a polling question. Please see http://stackoverflow.com/faq#dontask for details.

Answer (score 2):

yes. ABS it's free  [Advanced Bash-Scripting Guid](http://tldp.org/LDP/abs/html/)